# getcwd() with pointer returns "null"

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I'm trying to recall a bit about C programming.

And one task I found for myself - is to pass string's variable between functions with pointers.

So - what I want to do:

- create an array;
- create a pointer to this array;
- pass pointer as an argument to another function;
- call `getcwd()` inside second function;
- print result.

And here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int ch_str(char point1[]) {
    printf("Point 1: %s\n", point1);
}

int getpath (char point2[]) {
    printf("Path: %s\n", getcwd(point2, sizeof(point2)));
}

int main () {

    char str[20] = "this is string";
    char *pStr;
    pStr = &str;

    ch_str(pStr);

    char pathname[1024];
    char *pPathname;
    pPathname = &pathname;

    getpath(pPathname);

    printf("Direct: %s\n", getcwd(pathname, sizeof(pathname)));

    return 0;
}
```

`ch_str()` here - is just "test" for me, to be sure I'm doing right (he-he) with pointers. And - this part works.

But `getcwd()` with pointer as an argument - just retun "null":

> ```
> $ ./deploy
> Point 1: this is string
> Path: (null)
> Direct: /home/setevoy/ci
> ```

I suppose - here is some (big...) misunderstanding of the pointers in C from my side, but:

> The `getcwd()` function copies an absolute pathname of the current working directory to the array pointed to by buf

Array (`pathname[1024]`) passed with the pointer `pPathname`, so - why `getcwd()` can't save path to `pathname[1024]` location? What I can't see here?

Comment: `printf("Path: %s\n", getcwd(point2, sizeof(point2)));` what do you expect ` sizeof(point2)` to be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, arrays as function arguments are passed by-reference, not by-value.

It means that in your code, in function `getpath` the size of `char point2[]` is the size of `char *`, not the size of the array pointed by the argument.

Since the size of the pointer is too small to contain the whole path, `NULL` is returned instead. From `getcwd` manpage:

> The getcwd() function copies an absolute pathname of the current working directory to the array pointed to by buf, which is of
>   length size.
>          **If the length of the absolute pathname of the current working directory, including the terminating null byte, exceeds `size` bytes, NULL  is      returned**, and errno is set to ERANGE; an application should check for this error, and allocate a larger buffer if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, just found my mistake myself :-)
`getpath(pPathname, sizeof(pPathname));` fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass array as argument, function will only get pointer to the first element. In this process information about array size is lost. So there is your problem.

`getcwd(point2, sizeof(point2)));` This `sizeof()` is problem.

Read more here: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Answer (score 1):

Quoting `getcwd` manpages:

> RETURN VALUES
>
> ```
>  Upon successful completion, a pointer to the pathname is returned.  Oth-
>  erwise a NULL pointer is returned and the global variable errno is set to
>  indicate the error.  In addition, getwd() copies the error message asso-
>  ciated with errno into the memory referenced by buf.
> ```

So you can print errno (optionnaly, you can use strerror(3)) to get the reason the call failed.

Your code basically works on my computer, although my compiler complains a lot about your casts.

I don't get why you want to use this array, the manpage states that if you do not provide a buffer, it will be allocated, and you'll have to use `free(3)` on it. So basically, your code could just be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* getpath (void) {
  char *path = getwd(NULL);
  printf("Path: %s\n", path);
  return path;
}

int main () {
  char * dir = getpath();
  printf("I've got current path: %s\n", dir);
  free (dir);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But getcwd() with pointer as an argument - just retun "null":

If you replace your original `getpath` with the following `getpath2`, you would see the expected behavior:

```
int getpath2 (char *point2) {
    printf("Path2: %s\n", getcwd(point2, 1024));
}
```

Now why does this work, and your original `getpath` doesn't?

First check the prototype of `getcwd`:

`char *getcwd(char *buf, size_t size);`

You see that it expects a pointer `buf`, not an array. You argue that, wait, isn't that an array parameter decays to pointer? That's right. But that the problem is your `sizeof`, which now is the sizeof a pointer, not an array, so it's (usually) 4.

But it still doesn't explain the `null` output? So carry on with the function description:

> If the length of the absolute pathname of the current working
>          directory, including the terminating null byte, exceeds size bytes,
>          NULL is returned.

Here because 4 is not enough space, so you see null output.